# Windows 8 no longer sends sound to headphones when plugged in

Tags: windows-8, audio

Normally Windows 8 redirects audio output to my headphone jack when a cable is plugged in. But as of a few days ago, it no longer does this. How can I restore this functionality?

**My audio devices**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Device Management**

[image]
(no unrecognized devices)

Comment: It *could* be a software/driver error, but how do you know for sure that the jack sensing mechanism is not broken?

Comment: Good question. Is there any way to check?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. You could try a Linux/WinPE LiveCD/USB, but I don't think advanced soundcard-specific features will be enabled in such an environment that uses generic drivers. You can try deleting all the audio devices from Device Manager and reinstalling the latest drivers, but if that doesn't fix it I guess only an OS reinstall would confirm whether it's a hardware issue or not.

Comment: Isn't there a built-in Windows diagnostic that says "Headphones are plugged in" or "Headphones aren't plugged in"?

Comment: Not that I know of, but most soundcards (even on-board ones) come with software that helps you run diagnostics, shows a visual display of which jacks have devices plugged in etc.

Comment: So I was [poking around](http://i.imgur.com/Kma1j.png) in the Sound windows when I noticed that the Headphones indicator said "Not plugged in". I set the default output device to Headphones while the cable was plugged in and it worked fine. I don't think that anything changed driverwise. Hardware failure is not off the table yet, but at least it's working for the time being.

Comment: I don't know... I haven't had any more problems with it. I guess you could check the "Not plugged in" indicator in the Sound window.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your headphones and select "Set as Default Device"

Comment: Pretty much that. I've had to do that in windows 7 as well

Comment: Does this reinstate the auto-switching behavior? I can no longer reproduce the problem so I can't verify your proposed solution. I think it may have been driver-related in my case, because I'm currently using the [default Windows 8 driver](http://i.imgur.com/dRhSNa8.png) instead of the one that the manufacturer supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select it as the default device because it doesn't consider it to be plugged in.

Comment: Assuming the poster has the headphones plugged in, how else would this solve it? This would be better as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if you use windows 8 and you plug in your earphones/headphones and you cannot hear anything, but the speakers work. Go to the loud speaker icon at the bottom right and right click it.then click sound manager. go to the advanced tab then click jack information. click the picture of the audio jack hole and then click headphones. then click ok. Your sound should work now through your earphones/headphones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8 in HP Probook 14 then just go to **Control Panel** and search **Sound**. Select **Change sound card settings** and select the **Headphones** and set as default.

So when you plugin your earphones it will automatically switch to the earphone or any output devices through the 3.5 jack. Worked for me and when you remove phones it will pick internal by default.